# KeystoneJS edit file before AmazonS3 Upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, keystonejs

How do I edit the KeystoneJS file before it is uploaded to AmazonS3

It sounds like I should be able use an underscore method... but I don't know how to implement it
[image]

So for example, lets say I want to convert the file to base64 before it is uploaded to S3 and it is done with a function. How do I get the file, apply functions or methods to it, and then upload it.

```
Model.add({
    file: {         
        type: Types.S3File,
        filename: function(item, filename, originalname){                       
            return "fonts/original/" + item.slug + '.file';
        },

        // ** // ** // ** // ** // ** // ** 
        // Seems like it should go here...
        // On upload EVENT convert file to base64 and upload to S3
        // ** // ** // ** // ** // ** // ** 

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your image using the save event before submit the model

```
Model.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
   // Your code for convert the image to base 64
    this.imageBase64 = yourEncodedImage
    next();
});
```

Comment: This is on the right track... because it makes the event... but it don't pass in the file.